# Priortizing item select output

Tags: anylogic

If you have a proces flow cosider.
Swagging- *annealing* - brazing- tacking-cutting- buffing- *annelaing* - below bend-sleeve fit-sleeve cut- packaging. I want the process to be swagging-annealing-brazing-tacking-cutting-buffing-annealing this batch  to complete. Than from annealing this batch should go next to below bending-sleevefit-sleevecut- and packaging.
Select outputs process logic

Comment: Can you clarify your question and what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you question is... how to wait for a full batch to be completed before you send all the items to the next part of the process all togehter...

If that's the case you can use a wait block that will review if all the items of the batch are ready, and when this condition is met, you can send all the items to the batch block if you need to batch them, or send them independently  to the next part of the process.

you can see more details on how to do this in my blog:
https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/